# Find the last row in the dataframe in 10 sec from current timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

So I've a time series which is sampled more frequently than a second (i.e. I may have 2-5 samples for each second, sampled at different microseconds). I want to have a calculated column in the dataframe which is the last entry in a 10 second window from the current index time.

There may not be an entry exactly 10 sec after, hence I'm trying to use the last entry just before 10 sec. The index is a DateTimeIndex

I've written a simple loop to do this, wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
for row_index in df.index:
   df['calculate']=(df[df.index<row_index+pd.Timedelta('10s')][-1])
```

Example

```py
timestamp               value. calculate
2020-01-27 09:30:00.100 6.     42
2020-01-27 09:30:00.803 10.    25
2020-01-27 09:30:06.000 42.    25
2020-01-27 09:30:10.102 25.    25
2020-01-27 09:33:01.801 3.     20 
2020-01-27 09:33:05.100 10.    20
2020-01-27 09:33:11.700 20.    20
```

Comment: Could you provide some example data? Preferably a df before-state and a df desired-state

Comment: @DSteman added the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `df` to be your dataframe without the expected `calculate` column. You may create a dummy dataframe called `df_minus10` where the timestamp is 10 second before than the one from `df`.

```
df_minus10 = df.copy().rename(columns={'value': 'calculate'})
df_minus10['timestamp'] -= pd.Timedelta(seconds=10)
```

Then you can use `pd.merge_asof` to pick, for each timestamp in `df`, the largest timestamp from the dummy that is smaller-or-equal to it.

```
pd.merge_asof(df, df_minus10, on='timestamp', direction='backward')
```

Please time with your data to confirm whether this is more efficient.